# How are these two questions duplicates?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, specific-question

I recently saw that [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93421/mirrors-into-infinity) has been closed as a duplicate, and I couldn't disagree more, but for some reason it has [passed review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/149686) with a Leave Closed outcome.

- [The currently-closed question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93421/mirrors-into-infinity) asks, in essence,

  > Could someone [...] explain why the reflections [between two opposite mirrors] curve away instead of meeting at a perspective point within the reflections?

  i.e. entirely a geometric affair.
- [The proposed duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92301/what-color-would-you-see-if-you-place-2-mirrors-in-opposit-when-one-is-a-one-way) asks what would happen if one of the mirrors were 'one-way' and the observation were done from behind it (in a pretty rambling way), involving a completely different set of concepts, and also an invalid premise (the existence of one-way mirrors) that requires careful unthreading in the leading answer that makes up the bulk of the required response, and which is entirely absent from the currently-closed question.

How on Earth are these two duplicates?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I looked at it again and I would have to agree with you. I voted to reopen, though I'm not sure why I voted to close the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, those are very different questions.  Currently both are open.